# graphing columns from a CSV that includes null values- python

Tags: python, csv, null

I am relatively new to python and I am running into a lot of issues.
I am trying to create a graph using two columns from a csv file that contains many null values. Is there a way to convert a null value to a zero or delete the row that contains null values in certain columns?

Comment: yes there is a way to do this, but how exactly are the 'null' values formatted in your csv file? and what are you using in python to parse the csv file?

Answer (score 1):

Your question as asked is underspecified, but I think if we pick a concrete example, you should be able to figure out how to adapt it to your actual use case.

So, let's say your values are all either a string representation of a float, or an empty string representing null:

```
A,B
1.0,2.0
2.0,
,3.0
4.0,5.0
```

And let's say you're reading this using a `csv.reader`, and you're explicitly handling the rows one by one with some `do_stuff_with` function:

```
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    next(reader) # skip header
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        a, b = map(float, row)
        do_stuff_with(a, b)
```

Now, if you want to treat null values as 0.0, you just need to replace `float` with a function that returns `float(x)` for non-empty `x`, and `0.0` for empty `x`:

```
def nullable_float(x):
    return float(x) if x else 0.0

with open('foo.csv') as f:
    next(reader) # skip header
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        a, b = map(nullable_float, row)
        do_stuff_with(a, b)
```

If you want to skip any rows that contain a null value in column B, you just check column B before doing the conversion:

```
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    next(reader) # skip header
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if not row[1]:
            continue
        a, b = map(nullable_float, row)
        do_stuff_with(a, b)
```